# Immutable.js and shortcut for getting at a key entry

Tags: immutable.js

So, I am using Immutable.js and had a normal Immutable.Map and had to switch up the object a little because it kept sorting the object when I didn't want it to (previously, I was using a hash, now as you see, an array). Even an OrderedMap didn't work, so I put the "new" object like so, and now of course, the obj retains its ordering. BUT, now I have to iterate thru it every time I want to get a specific ID. Seems wasteful, I was curious if there is a helper function in which I can just request a key (id), in this case, and get back the appropriate obj.

```
"sneakers": Immutable.List([
    [{_id: 1, color: "red", price: 250}],
    [{_id: 1638, color: 728, price: 90}]
```

etc...

so, if I wanted the obj in which the _id is 1638, I'd have to filter thru it. Previously I could just "getIn". Is there a quick way with Immutable.js given this data structure?

Comment: Is there a reason you care about the so called "sorting" within the `Map`?

Comment: yeah, because I have a default view that follows the objects structure order. I think having to create a secondary container for default view array and iterating over that seemed wasteful when I should be able to assure order via my object structure. I understand hashes can't assure order - I was hoping there was a built-in feature that allowed an ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution, but if you have always one object inside inner array and all `_id`'s are unique, you can use:

```
 sneakers.find(function(data) {
    return data.find(function(innerArr) {
      return innerArr.get("_id") === 1638
    })
  }).get(0).toJS();
```

In this solution, you do not need to iterate all List, it returns when it finds first occurrence.

A small reminder: Immutable.List converts your list to immutable only for one level, inner array is still mutable. You should use fromJS() instead of List. My solution works for fromJS() usage.

Comment: thanks.. yeah - I thought there was something a bit less intrusive than find, but with destructuring I was able to reduce the code a bit, thanks.